# Upgraded to OS X EI Capitan and my Canon MG2240 will print but not Scan

Tags: macos

I have uploaded the latest printer Driver for the 2240 ( mcpd-mac-mg2200-11_7_1_0-ea17_2-2.dmg ).

Not sure where to from here

Kind regards

Alan

Comment: Did you install the driver software and reconnect the Canon in System Preferences?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need to install software to run the scanner, which Canon seems to call "software" instead of "drivers."

[This link will take you to the page where you can select what looks like a safe download.](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2240.aspx?type=download&language=EN&os=OS%20X%2010.11%20(El%20Capitan)) (Note: this link does NOT initiate a download.)

Just scroll down to the Scan Utility.

[image: Scan Utility]

Comment: You should be able to scan using Canon drivers only, without downloading/installing additional Canon software

Answer (score 0):

Patrix - On checking Printers and Scanners, the Printer is loaded and there is a tab Print/Scan and it was on Print. Changing to Scan has sorted out the problem. Silly me, but in the past I just had to press the Scan button on the Printer and she worked. So all sorted thank you very much.

As for the Canon software, I did download it and it works just fine and thank you too.

Thanks very much for the help guys, much appreciated.

Alan ....Durban    South Africa.

Comment: Please edit your original question with additional details or answers to questions instead of posting them as an answer. Once you have enough reputation you'll be able to comment on posts as well.